# Alsa+pulseaudio settings at reboot

Tags: alsa, pulseaudio

I have a xonar DG asus on slackware linux(module is snd-oxygen)
Works perfect but only if select as analog output the multichannel
as you can see from alsamixer

[image]

The problem is at reboot..the setting "analog output" return to "headphones"
And i can get no sound until i redo alsamixer and select "multichannel"
again.
The command

```
alsactl --file ~/.config/asound.state store
```

doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

Solution found,on my .bash_profile i put this line

```
alsactl --file ~/.config/asound.state restore
```

Comment: So it looks like the "store" command *did* work, you just didn't know how to use it. :-) BTW, many distros restore the sound state on boot (e.g. Debian via alsa-utils, in `/var/lib/alsa/asound.state`), and save it on shutdown.

Comment: If this is a system-wide setting, consider using `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` instead.

Comment: Yes i know rc.local is best for system-wide,but i use only with one user so .bash_profile is ok